# How to SFTP uploaded files from php I can't access

Tags: php, html

Please suggest me.I'm uploading file in a server SFTP by JPG, PNG, PDF, word document. When an uploaded file in a server display successfully attached but I saw created directory in a subfolder unable to open.

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
 $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
 $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf");
if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
$errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
if($file_size > 255097152){
$errors[]='File size must be exactly 2 MB';
  }
if(empty($errors)==true){

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"contact/uploads/fil2/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
}
```

I have to access and download the uploaded file from server JPG, PNG, PDF, Word document.

Comment: Did you set the correct permissions on the `contact/updates/fil2/` directory? Also your error messages are confusing: "please choose jpeg or png" but you also allow pdf, "file size must be exactly 2 MB" but it should be less or equal to 2 MB.

Comment: I really appreciate your help in resolving this problem Mr.Bram Versraten.Yes I have same directory.I have to upload in a server like PDF,Word doc,JPG,PNG file.When I was completed all formalities its display on screen success but couldn't able to get the file from server.